# How to duplicate a group of objects in Planet Coaster?

Tags: planet-coaster

I have just started playing Planet Coaster and I have noticed in some YouTube videos that the player is able to duplicate a *group* of objects but I am unable to figure out from the videos how they do it - they must be using some hotkey I think.

For example, I see people surrounding trees with submerged rocks (= with just the tips of them above ground level) in a circular fashion to make some stone border around it. They do this by placing two rocks that are on the opposing edges of the circle then clone the them both, and rotate the clone around the centroid which makes the whole process faster.

I am aware that there is a 'Duplicate` button at the top-right corner of the screen when an object is selected but for some reason, when I have more than 1 object selected, it just disappears, I can only see move/edit/advanced edit/destroy buttons.

How can I do this?

Comment: I haven't played the game myself, but a lot of programs and games use Ctrl+D to duplicate, or Ctrl+Drag to duplicate and move the selection. Have you checked the controls settings/key bindings?

Comment: Use the multi-select tool then save the selection as blueprint, you are able to paste them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only duplicate multiple scenery objects when they are part of a building. While you edit a building, you can select multiple objects by holding ctrl or the multi-select tool. You can then duplicate them all at once. If you don't want the scenery to be associated with a building, there is a trick:

1. Place a single wall to start with a new building
2. Place the scenery objects using duplication as you need
3. When you re finished, select all the scenery objects and click on "separate from building"
4. Delete the original wall

Comment: Already figured this out, but thank you anyway, others might find it helpful. Note that 3. is redundant provided that you are going to delete the dummy building object anyway. (However, just submerging it into the ground might be more useful, since you never know when you might fiddle them a bit more together.)